# Transfinite Recursion Theorem - Particular case - Enderton

Tags: set-theory, well-orders, transfinite-recursion

I have the following theorem for any formula $\gamma(x,y)$:

> *Theorem of Transfinite Recursion*: Given a well-ordered set $A$ such that for any $f$ there is a unique $y$ such that $\gamma(f,y)$ holds, then there is a unique function $F$ with domain $A$ such that $\gamma\big(F\upharpoonright\text{seg }t,F(t)\big)$ holds for all $t\in A$.

Now I'm reading through the proof of *Well-Ordering Theorem* $\implies$ *Zorn's Lemma*, for which the author has considered an arbitrary set $\mathscr A$, which can be endowed with some well-order $<$.

Then he says that the *Transfinite Recursion Theorem* give us the function $F:\mathscr A\to 2$ such that for every $A\in \mathscr A$

$$F(A)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if for every } B<A \text{ such that } F(B)=1 \text{ we have } B\subseteq A\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

How can I see that the *Theorem of Transfinite Recursion* permit this? What would $\gamma(x,y)$ be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the following?:

$\gamma(x,y)= \big(y=1 \land \varphi(x)\big)\lor\big(y=0\land \lnot\varphi(x)\big)$

where $\varphi(x)=\forall\,z\;\big(z\in\text{dom}(f)\to z\subseteq h(z)\big)$

where $h:\mathscr A\to\mathscr A$, so $h(z)=\text{the least element of }\mathscr A \text{ such that it's strictly greater than every element of }z$.

I've defined $h$ in such a way so we get $h(\text{seg }t)=t.$